# Difficulty Grouping and Aggregating Large Dataset

Tags: r, aggregate, odb

I'm having trouble working with a very large data set. I have an Item ID, Purchase Date, and Purchase Quantity.

```
 str(Output0)
 'data.frame':  183847 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ D: Factor w/ 460 levels "2015-09-21","2015-09-24",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  $ P: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  $ Q: num  7 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

As a note, P=Item ID, D=Date, and Q=Purchase Quantity

I would like to sum the purchase quantity for each individual item by a 3 day period (So there may still be duplicate item IDs). For example:

```
P    Date      Purchase Q
1234     1/1/16         1
1235     1/1/16         1  
1235     1/2/16         1
1235     1/3/16         1
1444     1/1/16         1
1444     1/2/16         1
1444     1/3/16         1
```

Would look like:

```
ItemID    DateEndPoint  Purchase Q
1234       1/1/16         1
1235       1/3/16         3  
1444       1/3/16         3
```

I've tried using:

```
Output2 <- aggregate(Output0$Q, by=list(PS=P,
               Date = cut(as.Date(Output0$D, format="%d/%m/%Y"),breaks="3 day")), FUN=sum)
```

but it is coming up with this error:

> Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In min.default(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  :
>     no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   2: In max.default(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  :
>     no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

I'd also like to do the same for other time periods as needed (1 day, 1 week) so something reproducible would be wonderful.

In response to P Lapointe: I tried the below and it looks great, except that the last column is totalling all items across all dates instead of for each period

```
 Output1 <- POData%>%mutate(Date=as.Date(POData$`PO Date`,"%m-%d-%Y"),Date_Group=cut(Date,breaks="3 days"))%>%  group_by(POData$`ItemID`,Date_Group)%>%summarise(DateEndPoint=max(Date),Purchase_Q=sum(POData$`POQty`,na.rm=TRUE))
```

It displays as:

```
 > View(Output1)
 > str(Output1)
 Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    116749 obs. of  4 variables:
  $ POData$`Item ID`: int  11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
  $ Date_Group      : Factor w/ 216 levels "2015-09-21","2015-09-24",..: 4 6 11 13 14 15 18 19 24 25 ...
  $ DateEndPoint    : Date, format: "2015-10-02" "2015-10-08" ...
  $ Purchase_Q      : num  2691020 2691020 2691020 2691020 2691020 ...
  - attr(*, "vars")= chr "POData$`Item ID`"
  - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did u tried DPLYR package?

Comment: @AntonCH No I have not yet - What would you recommend?

Comment: @SuttonMurray I imagine you have more than 3 days in your real life example. Do you want a rolling sum (calculated every day) or 3-day periods only with no overlap?

Comment: @PLapointe You're correct, definitely a lot more (Total of one year and 100k+ purchase orders). I'd like to get a rolling sum for three day periods with no overlap by item. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @SuttonMurray read this https://rpubs.com/bradleyboehmke/data_wrangling. Very simple and fast data manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do that with `dplyr`. Note that I extended your example by one day to show that it can handle additional 3-day groups. Basically, you want to create a new Date_group column to group on. Then, `summarise`.

```
df <- read.table(text="P    Date      Purchase_Q
1234     1/1/16         1
1235     1/1/16         1  
1235     1/2/16         1
1235     1/3/16         1
1444     1/1/16         1
1444     1/2/16         1
1444     1/3/16         1
1444     1/5/16         1",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df%>%
  mutate(Date=as.Date(Date,"%m/%d/%y"),Date_group=cut(Date,breaks="3 days")) %>%
  group_by(P,Date_group) %>%
  summarise(DateEndPoint=max(Date),Purchase_Q=sum(Purchase_Q,na.rm=TRUE))

      P Date_group DateEndPoint Purchase_Q
  <int>     <fctr>       <date>      <int>
1  1234 2016-01-01   2016-01-01          1
2  1235 2016-01-01   2016-01-03          3
3  1444 2016-01-01   2016-01-03          3
4  1444 2016-01-04   2016-01-05          1
```

Comment: @P Lapoint Thank you! It seems to be working well, except for the last column, which is equaling the total sum across all items/dates (2691020) instead of over each time period. I names my dataframe "POData". I just pasted the new code up above in the original post. Is there anything you can see that may be causing it to not total correctly?

Comment: @SuttonMurray With `dplyr`, you usually don't need to put `POData$` inside the code. In this case, it tells R ignore the grouping. Try this instead: `Output1 <- POData%>%mutate(Date=as.Date('PO Date',"%m-%d-%Y"),Date_Group=cut(Date,breaks="3 days"))%>%  group_by(ItemID,Date_Group)%>%summarise(DateEndPoint=max(Date),Purchase_Q=sum(POQty,na.rm=TRUE))`